# MySQL - Union or join?

Tags: mysql, join, union

I'm trying to collect statistic data in one SQL query for the convenience of having the date sorted automatically in a union. It is really only one table but I want to count different cases of data.

The table I have looks something like this:

```
ID   In          Wanted
441  2011-03-14  0
439  2011-03-14  1
442  2011-03-14  0
428  2011-03-13  1
431  2011-03-13  1
425  2011-03-11  0
423  2011-03-11  1
420  2011-03-09  1
```

I get close to the desired result with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  (SELECT date(In) n, count(date(In)) cntw, null cntl FROM items i WHERE Wanted=1 group by date(In))
union all
  (SELECT date(In) n, null cntw, count(date(In)) cntl FROM items i WHERE Wanted=0 group by date(In))
) Serie
Order by n DESC
```

But close isn't close enough :D The result i get is this:

```
n            cntw   cntl
2011-03-14   null   2
2011-03-14   1      null
2011-03-13   2      null
2011-03-11   null   1
2011-03-11   1      null
2011-03-09   1      null
```

What I want is to "blend" the results on the same line, by date:

```
n            cntw   cntl
2011-03-14   1      2
2011-03-13   2      null
2011-03-11   1      1
2011-03-09   1      null
```

As you can see there is only ONE row for each date.
Actually the most perfect result would be to even have the missing dates in there too:

```
n            cntw   cntl
2011-03-14   1      2
2011-03-13   2      null
2011-03-12   null   null
2011-03-11   1      1
2011-03-10   null   null
2011-03-09   1      null
```

...but I guess this isn't possible.

Thank you!

Comment: You should avoid using MySQL keywords in your field names (I mean the `In` field). Regarding question: isn't it possible to use `GROUP BY` somehow ?

Comment: Well, the name is actually `CheckIn` and the tables are a lot more complex than I showed here, I shortened it in my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select date(In) as n,
       sum(case when wanted = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as cntw,
       sum(case when wanted = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as cntl
    from items
    group by date(In)
    order by n desc
```

Comment: Actually, when playing around a bit, your solution was the most flexible one, and I can understand it without reading up on t syntax :D I managed to add more advanced selections to your model.

Answer (score 1):

You want to join them, I think this will work

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT date(In) n, count(date(In)) cntw, null cntl FROM items i WHERE Wanted=1 group by date(In)) as a
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT date(In) n, null cntw, count(date(In)) cntl FROM items i WHERE Wanted=0 group by date(In)) as b
ON a.n = b.n
Order by n DESC
```

But I think this can be done in a single query, like this perhaps?

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpFoo (
    SomeDate datetime,
    Wanted bit
)

INSERT INTO #tmpFoo VALUES ('2011-03-11', 0)
INSERT INTO #tmpFoo VALUES ('2011-03-11', 1)
INSERT INTO #tmpFoo VALUES ('2011-03-12', 0)
INSERT INTO #tmpFoo VALUES ('2011-03-12', 1)
INSERT INTO #tmpFoo VALUES ('2011-03-14', 0)

SELECT  SomeDate n, 
        count(NULLIF(Wanted,0)) cntw, 
        count(NULLIF(Wanted,1)) cntl 
    FROM #tmpFoo i  
    GROUP BY SomeDate
```

Comment: I'd do `USING (N)` rather than `ON a.n = b.n`.

Comment: @Romain, I didn't like that approach anyhow, I've added to my answer with a simpler, single, no sub-query solution

Comment: +1v Thank you! it works as a charm! I used the USING(n) version (from Romain) instead of ON a.n = b.n. Now I will sit down and analyse what you did so I can learn how this works :)

Comment: @Max Kielland, the second solution I wrote is quite simple.  You select from the query, grouping by date.  Count, will only include values that are NOT NULL, so, you use NULLIF to return null when the Wanted field is not what you want to include in the count.  This allows you to count both columns in a single query.  The initial create table, and inserts are only there so I could test.

Comment: Hmm, I need to be able to do some more complex calculation such as `count(NULLIF(Wanted,0) AND out IS NULL) cntw`. I guess you get the point, I need to use more like a WHERE statement to select the cases I need to count.

Comment: @Max Kielland, you could put a `CASE` statement in the `COUNT` instead of using `NULLIF`, return null when you want to exclude it from the count.  Example: `select count(case when 1=2 then 1 else null end)` you just need to change the `1=2` part to your condition

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I didn't see your last comment until it was too late... But your `CASE` suggestion is almost identical to Joe Stefanelli's solution (`SUM` instead of `COUNT`). Anyway, everyone got some credit for helping :D Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You'd use a `LEFT JOIN` using your `n` field to get the dates where you have stuff... Then you'd `UNION` this with a query that gives you the lines where there's nothing (the info you give above doesn't allow me to help in what query this would be :D).